# not wanting text of future slides after \pause to appear

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, presentations, pause

I have a slide containing an example block with 5 lines and each of them is separated by `\pause` command. During a presentation however, when I click the button the first line brightens and 4 other lines are fade and visible in the background. Then when i click again the second line also brightens so 2 lines are brightens (so there are two bright lines on screen now).

Question: After the first click of the button, I DO NOT want the other 4 lines to appear (*EVEN* in the background faded). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Do you want the lines to _replace_ one another or to appear _below_ each other (in a list-type form)? Also, are you using any themes or non-standard settings?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can either use the `\onslide` command that "prints the text" (i.e. it occupies space), but do not display it, or the `\only` command that prints and display the text *only* on slide *x* (the rest of the time, it is as if you had no text). Details and examples in *§ 9.3 Commands with Overlay Specifications* of the [beamer user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

Comment: It helps us if you post the minimal code needed for us to see your result.  It takes a few minutes of your time, but it saves everyone else that much time, and lets us get to the meat of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your code this is just a guess: do you have any `\setbeamercovered{...}` in your code? Then remove it, because the default beamer behaviour is to set future items to invisible.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc \pause

    def
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```